# Why is the syntax for a worksheet IF() function with optional parameters different from UDF?

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, worksheet-function

Never really deeply thought about this but why does an `=IF()` function require you to *pass* commas even though the last 2 parameters are Optional?

```
=IF(logical_test, [value_if_true], [value_if_false])
```

Why can't we just call it

```
=IF(TRUE)
```

to get `TRUE` (*default return value when **logical_test** evaluated to TRUE*)

we have to call it providing the two commas in between even when leaving the parameters missing/empty...

```
=IF(TRUE, ,)
```

In a UDF when using Optional Parameters we will not need to pass the commas (*much simpler version of the original IF, error handling not implemented as not needed here*)

```
Public Function MYIF(logical_test, Optional value_if_true$ = "TRUE", Optional value_if_false$ = "FALSE")
    MYIF = IIf(Evaluate(logical_test), value_if_true, value_if_false)
End Function
```

and when calling from a spreadsheet we can omit the commas

```
=MYIF(TRUE)
```

Anyone, besides Spolsky ;), is aware of the reason why do we need to provide commas when using the native `=IF()`?

---

I am in Excel 2010 but just have noticed that [2007 requires 2 parameters](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/if-function-HP010069829.aspx).. Still, in 2010 the function definition shows 1st as required, last 2 optional. Any explanation?

---

Update:

I am aware of the `=1=1` and `=AND(TRUE,FALSE)` syntax, I am **not** looking for an alternative to a short-hand version of the `=IF()`. Instead what I am asking is

**why do the commas need to be provided with the original `=IF()` since the last 2 parameters are Optional Parameters?**

Comment: "we have to call it providing the two commas"  Well, not necessarily. One comma is also accepted: `=IF(TRUE,)`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett heh nice never knew that actually

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Optional argument" can apparently have two distinct meanings for Excel functions:

1. the optional argument may be omitted;
2. the *value* of the optional argument may be omitted.

Sometimes both are allowed, sometimes only #2 is allowed.

Look at the documentation for `IF`:

> `IF(logical_test, [value_if_true], [value_if_false])`
>
> [...]
>
> `value_if_false`  Optional. [...]
>
> If `logical_test` evaluates to `FALSE` and **the `value_if_false` argument is omitted** [...], the `IF` function returns the logical value `FALSE`.
>
> If `logical_test` evaluates to `FALSE` and ***the value of* the `value_if_false` argument is omitted** [...], the `IF` function returns the value 0 (zero).

Okay, both are allowed. So `=IF(FALSE,)` (argument omitted) returns `FALSE`, while `=IF(FALSE,,)` (argument there but value omitted) returns 0.

But for the `value_if_true` argument, only option #2 is allowed according to the documentation. There is no provision for omitting this argument entirely; only omitting its value is supported. So `=IF(TRUE,)` and `=IF(TRUE,,)` (argument there but value omitted) both return 0, while `=IF(TRUE)` (argument omitted entirely) is unsupported and therefore does not compile.

The above describes the documented and supported behaviour. Of course this doesn't answer the deeper question of "why" it is like that. My answer to that is, I don't know. I'm sure the makers of Excel had a good reason, or at least thought they did.

---

As for UDFs, they are written in VBA and their `Optional` parameters are governed by VBA's rules, which are different. There is no such thing as omitting "the value of" a parameter in VBA functions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jean-Francois. I see now that the whole point is the different meanings for Optional Arguments between Excel Functions and VBA. As you noticed, only developers of Excel can actually explain why it's that way but I am quite happy with your answer, well done! What really confused me to start off with was Excel saying `IF(logical_test, [value_if_true], [value_if_false])` which made me think both args were Optional, but in reality the second one is required at least in the form of *existing* there even though it could not have a value.